# How I can handle two different currencies on the same Excel sheet for large data?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to get the all product  prices by Egyptian pound and bearing in mind the various of US dollar rate in every year

[image]

Comment: Your edit is simply copying your later question and failing to address any of my comments: **show us the formulas you are using, what you have tried and where you are stuck. Explain your problem, show your working.** Go through the problem explaining the steps you took to *attempt* to solve the problem. *Do not simply leave a problem and expect people to do your work for you*.

Comment: lets take the point step by step you really informed me how I can handle it if I have specific years like 2015, 2016 and 2017 and I really got it clearly

but the current situation how can I make Vlookup with days I have sheet contains five years and each year contains 365 days so it`s totally different that why I am sending you again 

so I cant make vlookup with table like years

do you get my point of view believe me I am not abuser or seeking for wasting your time

Comment: The answers below both show perfectly good and workable solutions to give you an idea of how to start solving the problem *as it was originally stated in this question*. On your second question I gave you a link to edit *that* question to provide details that would have made it a distinct question showing what your exact problem was. If you had edited it to show *why* the solutions here did not work for that exact problem then it could have been reopened. This question now needs to be rolled back as you are, unfairly to those who answered, moving the goalposts.

Comment: [Edit your new question.](https://superuser.com/posts/1219493/edit) Describe how you **attempted** to solve the problem and what did not work. I "get" that the problems are subtly different, but you need to show us exactly how and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Mr. Mokubai you will find the below formula mentioned in the first answer

=IF(C2="US Dollar",VLOOKUP(D2,$G$1:$H$4,2,FALSE),1)*B2

it works fine with years but its impossible to make table for 5 years * 365 days

if I am wrong tell me please

Comment: Did reach anything regarding this point?

Comment: Doing a vlookup on that large a set might be *impractical* but it is by no means *impossible*. If you want help then you have to help us to help you by [editing your newer question.](https://superuser.com/posts/1219493/edit) showing where you are having trouble applying what you have learnt here so it can be reopened. There are many ways of solving this problem but without you even making an attempt there is no way for us to be able to tell you where you are going wrong. We are not a "gimme the codes" service, we expect a minimal amount of effort on your side.

Answer (score 5):

1. create a "lookup" table for USD/EGP rate per year:
   [image]
2. use this formula:
   `=IF(C2="US Dollar",VLOOKUP(D2,$G$1:$H$4,2,FALSE),1)*B2`
   (`VLOOKUP` gets the current exchange rate, `IF` checks whether it's necessary to exchange)

[image]

Comment: Dear I need your support for more inquiries what shall I do I am a new comer and dont aware about the policy

Comment: @Tika22: maybe you could start by reading [how do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok I will next time but could you please give me answer for my second question I am really need it urgently and accept my apology

Answer (score 2):

```
=IF(C2="$",(IF(D2=15,B2*5,IF(D2=16,B2*6,B2*7))),B1)
```

[image]

I have to say that Mate's coding is a more expandable version as you would have to change the coding every year with mine.

I just used example figures, so feel free to change my 15 / 16 / 17 to 2015 etc..., also I used 5,6,7 as the year conversion rates. Change these values in the coding where required.